# Filter recycler view containing edittext in each row

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am facing a problem using search view filter in recycler view containing edittext in each row. Normally if i don't use filter my edittext values don't change in recycler view but when i filter using search view, values in edittext not remain same.When i type something in search view all the values become same in edit text, it loses all values added during initialization also when i clear the search view all value in edittext become same or change any rows value it repeats after each 4 or 5 rows.

Below is my Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    SearchView searchView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ListAdapterr listAdapterr;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        List<Info> listData = new ArrayList<>();
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop HP",10));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Fujitsu",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Lenovo",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Acer",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Stand",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Cooler",3));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Battery",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop HDD",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop RAM",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Display",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop Cleaner",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam2",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam3",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam4",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam5",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam6",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam7",150));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam8",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam9",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam10",100));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam11",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam12",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam13",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam14",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam15",25));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam16",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam17",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam19",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam22",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam21",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam23",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam24",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam25",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam232",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam234",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam123",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam332",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam223",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam112",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam3123",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam4123",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam3411",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam3222",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam3111",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam3333",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam4444",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam411",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam422",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam4223",1));
        listData.add(new Info("Laptop USB Webcam41233",1));

        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sview);
        search(searchView);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.review);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false));
        listAdapterr = new ListAdapterr(listData,R.layout.info_layout,this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapterr);
    }

    private void search(SearchView searchView) {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                listAdapterr.getFilter().filter(newText);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Adapter Class:

```
public class ListAdapterr extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterr.MListHolder> implements Filterable {

    List<Info> mList;
    List<Info> filteredResult;
    int rowLayout;
    Context context;

    public class MListHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView tvitem;
        EditText etquan;

        public MListHolder(View v) {
            super(v);

            tvitem = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            etquan = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        }
    }

    public ListAdapterr(List<Info> mList, int rowLayout, Context context) {
        this.mList = mList;
        this.filteredResult = mList;
        this.rowLayout = rowLayout;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public ListAdapterr.MListHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout,parent,false);
        return new MListHolder(v);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ListAdapterr.MListHolder holder, int position) {
         final Info info = filteredResult.get(position);
         holder.tvitem.setText(info.getItemName());
         holder.etquan.setText(String.valueOf( info.getQuantity()));
         holder.etquan.setTag(position);
         holder.etquan.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
             @Override
             public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

             }

             @Override
             public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                 if(charSequence.length() > 0){
                     int q = Integer.parseInt(charSequence.toString());
                     Log.d("TAG","---------------->"+q);
                     info.setQuantity(q);
//                     holder.etquan.setText(q);
                 }
             }

             @Override
             public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

             }
         });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return filteredResult.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter()  {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                String searchString = charSequence.toString();

                if(searchString.isEmpty()){
                    filteredResult.removeAll(mList);
                    filteredResult.addAll(mList);
                }
                else
                {

                    ArrayList<Info> filteredResultTwo = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(Info info : mList){
                        if(info.getItemName().toLowerCase().contains(charSequence)){
                            filteredResultTwo.add(info);
                        }
                    }

                    for(Info info: filteredResultTwo){
                        Log.d("TAGdata","Values------------------------>"+info.getQuantity());
                    }

                    filteredResult = filteredResultTwo;
                }

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = filteredResult;
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                filteredResult = (List<Info>) filterResults.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }


}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/pskink/cd3bbdd742b5b1905a790c76831b5d85/raw/c9cd53e807a7fcf72549c0fb0f275019cafb30b7/MatchableRVArrayAdapte%2520(pure%2520RecyclerView%2520style,%2520no%2520implicit%2520TextView%2520mapping)) generic `Filterable` adapter as a base class and override its `matches()` method

Comment: Can you please give an example......i have added the code but it's not working...

Comment: `class Adapter extends MatchableRVArrayAdapter<Info, Adapter.VH> { ...` and override two abstract methods + `matches()` method for filtering purposes

Comment: i have already overrided the abastract methods of the Filter class, please see my adapter class code above after that i  also added the matched method like you said..........but i am not getting the result.......

Comment: i dont see any class that extends `MatchableRVArrayAdapter`

Comment: public class ListAdapterr extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapterr.MListHolder> implements Filterable here is the declaration

Comment: so where is your class extending `MatchableRVArrayAdapter`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152880/discussion-between-noob-coder-and-pskink).

Comment: @Noob_coder solve your problem yes or no?

Comment: No i am working on it @Anand Diamond

Comment: What's your problem tell me.

Comment: i have solved the problem......with the help of pskink